# Plotting x^(1/3)

Tags: plotting

How do I get Mathematica to plot solutions on the left and right side of the y-axis instead of just the right side?

```
Plot[x^(1/3), {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> 3]
```

Edit:  I guess I should clarify.  See graph below.  Is there an easy way to plot negatives values for x?  (-8)^(1/3)=-2  but it's not plotting the left hand side.

[image]

Comment: could try reading the documentation maybe. Check axis and plotrange options.

Comment: @tsuresuregusa   I'm not sure what you mean.  Can you clarify?  I feel I am fairly proficient with axis and plotrange options, but apparently not.

Comment: `(-8)^(1/3)=-2`, How did you get this?  it is complex number?

Comment: Got it.  Didn't realize Mathematica solves over the complex numbers.  Use CubeRoot[] instead.

Comment: @MichaelMcCain didn't understand what you meant before the image, sorry.